# copy the path specified in the text file to the source link of anothe text file using a bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am doing a automation testing, my content is before start of test. I will copy the copying content path in a text file and this path one by one will has to be linked to the source path of the another bat file., this is the concept:

A text file containing paths specified line by line, I need to copy the first line of this path file to the another text file where this copied first line will be act as a source file path.

I am new to this.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: What language do you wish to use for this testing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you wish to do something along these lines, but it would be useful to hear more of what you're hoping to achieve.

```
for /f %%f in (textfile.txt) do call process.bat %%f
```

This line reads each line from textfile.txt and passes that line into process.bat for it to do something with that line. Save this code into a .bat file and create some other .bat file called process.bat (your subroutine). And change the name of textfile.txt above to your expected file. Or pass that in to the .bat file and use %1 to access it.

Comment: You may want to use `for /f "delims=" %%f in (textfile.txt) do call process.bat "%%f"` in case any of the paths have spaces in the text file.